# Flutter :How to pass List to Firestore where condetion

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How to pass a List as param to firestore where condition? To get all data meets the condition

ie:-

```
List<String> topicList ;
getData() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    topicList = pref.getStringList("topicSymbol");
}

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStreamQuery(String collPath) {
    List<String> filters ;
    return db
        .collection('$collPath')
        .where('Symbol', isEqualTo: getData()) // <---- the problem is here
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this approach: firstly getData is an async function and you are not awaiting to get the return list from get data. You want to call `await getData()` before the return call in getStreamQuery.
Secondly, you should use `.where('Symbol', isEqualTo: topicList)` in order to compare the lists (this is because getData() returns null)

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: im passing the getStreamQurey StreamBuilder, and when i did what you said its show error The argument type 'Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object>>'

Comment: and when i pass topicList to isEqualTo its return Null. but when i set for i.e isEqualTo: topicList[1] its work but it return only one result

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `await` in there, your `getData()` actually returns a `Future` - and you're failing to deal with that when calling it.

The simplest fix is to make `getStreamQuery` async too:

```
getData() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return pref.getStringList("topicSymbol");
}

Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getStreamQuery(String collPath) async {
    List<String> filters ;
    return db
        .collection('$collPath')
        .where('Symbol', isEqualTo: await getData())
        .snapshots();
}
```

When you call `getStreamQuery`, you'll need to use `await` there tool.

Comment: im passing the getStreamQurey StreamBuilder, and when i did what you said its show error The argument type 'Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object>>'

Comment: and when i pass topicList to isEqualTo its return Null.
but when i set for i.e isEqualTo: topicList[1] its work but it return only one result

Comment: As I said in my answer: you'll need to use `await` when calling `getStreamQurey` too.